Cómo puede ser NullPointerException?
Antes de que me crucifiquen, ya sé los motivos por los que sale un NullPointerException. Lo que no comprendo es por qué me da ese error en una variable final que ya ha sido inicializada:
public class ModeloTablaClientes
        extends DefaultTableModel {

    private final List<ClienteBean> CLIENTES = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> NOMBRES = new ArrayList<>();

    public ModeloTablaClientes(LinkedList<ClienteBean> clientes) {
        if (clientes != null && !clientes.isEmpty()) {
            CLIENTES.clear();
            CLIENTES.addAll(clientes);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        return CLIENTES.get(row).get(column);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return NOMBRES.get(column);
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return NOMBRES.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return CLIENTES.size();
    }
}

Concretamente salta cuando hace una llamada al método getRowCount(), indica que no pueder hacer una llamada a List.size() porque es null.
No lo comprendo. Me pueden ayudar a entender.
Gracias

Hola Jaia, sin ver todo el código es difícil saber, pero casi con seguridad, te está diciendo que no inicializaste ModeloTablaClientes, ese es el null que te indica, ya que lo que presumes no tiene sentido.

por otro lado, la condición del if, debería ser: clientes != null ya que CLIENTES siempre estará vacio.

Efectivamente no se inicializa la clase y por eso es null. Aunque no sé bien por qué. Y respecto al if, toda la razón del mundo. Gracias

Puedes poner un breakpoint en la línea donde declaras la variable. Si no me equivoco, el programa debería parar en el momento que se inicialice. También pon un watchpoint para ver cuándo cambia el valor de la variable. Eso debería ayudarte a descubrir el problema. En cada IDE se hace distinto así que averigua cómo se hace en el tuyo.

¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de cómo usas esta clase y el stack trace que aparece?

El problema es que getRowCount() indica que CLIENTES es null, lo cual sugiere que no se ha inicializado correctamente. Sin embargo, la variable está declarada como final e inicializada en su declaración:
private final List<ClienteBean> CLIENTES = new ArrayList<>();

La única forma en que CLIENTES podría ser null es si:
Otra parte del código está reasignando CLIENTES (lo cual es improbable por ser final).
La clase se está inicializando de forma incorrecta.
Por ejemplo, si hay un constructor adicional o un bloque de inicialización que podría causar que la inicialización de CLIENTES se sobrescriba o no se ejecute.
Verifica si hay constructores adicionales o código estático que podría estar afectando la inicialización.
Solución: Asegúrate de que el objeto ModeloTablaClientes esté completamente construido antes de usar métodos que dependan de esas listas.

No sé porqué, pero he realizado un debug y no se ejecuta el constructor de la clase, directamente salta al método rowCount(). No me explico cómo puede ser. Otra cosa interesante, es que realizando pruebas, he cambiado DefaultTableModel por AbstractTableModel, y o sopresa, funciona. El por qué y el por qué no, no lo sé, no conozco tan profundamente Java como para darle una explicación. Ojalá alguien conozca el por qué. En cualquier caso muchas gracias por la ayuda.

El error ocurre porque estás inicializando las listas CLIENTES y NOMBRES en línea, pero es posible que estés llamando a getRowCount() antes de que el constructor de ModeloTablaClientes haya sido ejecutado. Si la llamada ocurre antes de la inicialización del objeto, las listas podrían estar en un estado no inicializado, resultando en NullPointerException.

Te funciona la solucion?
